# Twitter API 404 errors - Python (continued)

Tags: python, api, for-loop, twitter, error-handling

I'm trying to use the GET users/lookup from the twitter API in a python script to identify screen name based on a list of users IDs. The script doesn't seem to be able to handle 404 errors, as I assume the whole request with 100 user IDs is not found by twitter, so the for loop doesn't even begin. How do I iterate over 100 user IDs at a time, while still respecting the rate limit, if one of the 100 IDs will cause the whole request to 404? Is there a way to handle this error while still getting the response for the other IDs in the same request? My experiments with "except Valueerror" didn't seem to solve this...

I'd very much appreciate any advice or tips you can give!

```
while total_request_counter <= request_total:
  while list_counter_last <= len(list)+100: #while last group of 100 items is lower or equal than total number of items in list#:
    while current_request_counter < 180:
        response = twitter.users.lookup(include_entities="false",user_id=",".join(list[list_counter_first:list_counter_last])) #API query for 100 users#
        for item in list[list_counter_first:list_counter_last]: #parses twitter IDs in the list by groups of 100 to record results#
            try: #necessary for handling errors#
                results = str(response)
                results = results[results.index("u'screen_name': u'",results.index(item)) + 18:results.index("',",results.index("u'screen_name': u'",results.index(item)) + 18)]#looks for username section in the query output#
                text_file = open("output_IDs.txt", "a") #opens current txt output / change path to desired output#
                text_file.write(str(item) + "," + results + "\n") #adds twitter ID, info lookup result, and a line skip to the txt output#
                text_file.close()
                error_counter = error_counter + 1
                print str(item) + " = " + str(results)
            except: #creates exception to handle errors#
                text_file = open("output_IDs.txt", "a") #opens current txt output / change path to desired output#
                text_file.write(str(item) + "," + "ERROR " + str(response.headers.get('h')) + "\n") #adds twitter ID, error code, and a line skip to the txt output#
                text_file.close()
                print str(item) + " = ERROR"
                continue 
        print "Succesfully processed " + str(error_counter) + " users of request number " + str(current_request_counter + 1) + ". " + str(179 - current_request_counter) + " requests left until break."   #confirms latest batch processing#
        print ""
        list_counter_first = list_counter_first + 100 #updates list navigation to move on to next group of 100#
        list_counter_last = list_counter_last + 100
        error_counter = 0 # resets error counter for the next round#
        current_request_counter = current_request_counter + 1 #updates current request counter to stay below rate limit of 180#
t = str(datetime.now())
print ""
print "Taking a break, back in 16 minutes. Approximate time left: " + str((len(list)/18000*15)-(15*total_request_counter)) + " minutes. Current timestamp: " + t
print ""
current_request_counter = 0
total_request_counter = total_request_counter + 1
time.sleep(960) #suspends activities for 16 minutes to respect rate limit#
```